# PHP mysql query counting repeating values in left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables - projects and sites.

I want to show a table with project number and site addresses, but where there's multiple sites per project show "Multiple Sites", and where there's no site assigned to a project show "No site".

So I would like my table to look like this:

| Project Number | Site Address |
| --- | --- |
| job1 | 123 Fake Street |
| job2 | 5 sydney street |
| job3 | Multiple Sites |
| job4 | No site |

But currently my table looks like this.

| Project Number | Site Address |
| --- | --- |
| job1 | 123 Fake Street |
| job2 | 5 sydney street |
| job3 | 1 First Street |
| job3 | 2 Second street |
| job4 | No site |

with job3 repeating.
My code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, 
        "SELECT projects.project_number,
            sites.address,
            sites.project_fk
            FROM projects
            LEFT JOIN sites
            ON projects.id = sites.project_fk");
?>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">Project Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Site</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo "<td>".$row["project_number"]."</td>";
                if ($row["address"] == null) {
                echo "<td>No Site</td>";
                } else {
                echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this? Do I have to create a new query which counts the number of 'sites' which are the same, and if so how do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need group by and count() in your SQL. Based on the count result you can tell whether there is one site, multiple sites or no sites. you will also need to select sites.address as group_concat(sites.address) and take out project_fk from SQL to avoid errors

Comment: BTW your question is neither mysqli not html related. And there is no such thing as "sqli" at all

Answer (score 0):

Use group by and case to determine if there are multiple, single or none addresses

```
SELECT projects.project_number,
        CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 then 'Multiple sites'
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 then sites.address
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 then 'No site'
        END as address
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN sites ON projects.id = sites.project_fk
GROUP BY projects.id
```